# What will happen if we use an Inductor in place of a Capacitor in Single phase Induction motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor, single-phase

So as the titles says, well i know that a capacitor give phase shift and that results in a rotating Magnetic Field. So i was wondering what will happen if we use a an inductor, i mean doesn't it create phase shift like capacitor and make rotating field ?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point about a coil that is series fed with a capacitor is that at the right frequency it will naturally produce a phase shift of 90 degrees and this creates a pseudo-rotating magnetic field that is good enough to start rotation in the correct direction. Consider this RLC circuit and response below: -

[image]

[Interactive tool](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html)

If the coil has an inductance of (say) of 100 mH and the capacitor is 100 uF (just as a thrown together example) then, at 50 Hz it will produce a phase angle for the coil voltage that is 90 degrees shifted from the main applied voltage.

If the coil inductance was 1 henry and the capacitor was 10 uF it would produce the same angle.

Single phase induction motor with start and run capacitor: -

[image]

The above diagram shows a single phase motor with a start capacitor and a run capacitor. Usually the start capacitor is bigger in value than the run capacitor and naturally tunes to a lower frequency hence produces a better starting torque. When the motor is up to (say) half-speed the centrifugal switch will open leaving just the run capacitor that is more "tuned" to running the motor at full speed.

Clearly there are some motors with only a run capacitor and some motors with only a start capacitor and this depends on application and power.

> So i was wondering what will happen if we use a an inductor, i mean
>   doesn't it create phase shift like capacitor and make rotating field ?

An external inductor replacing the capacitor won't change the phase angle of current in the start/run coil - it will be the same phase (or thereabouts) as the current in the main coil and there will be no rotation of field.

Answer (score 0):

The main winding of an induction motor is already very inductive, so it'd be difficult to make the phase shift of the auxiliary winding much greater. It is possible to do it the opposite way - if the auxiliary winding has a far lower turn count and is substantially less inductive than the main, enough phase difference is generated to create starting torque. This means that the current through the auxiliary winding is substantial, so it is often done with a centrifugal start switch, and disconnected once the motor has gained some speed. [image] (from [here](https://circuitglobe.com/split-phase-induction-motor.html))